# How do you enable a graphical interface for the Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client download?

Tags: redhat

I downloaded Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client 6.3 onto virtual box but it's only bring forth a command line interface when I login in using root. There is no graphical interface attached with the install. How do I remedy this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. You need more than 512mb + 128mb of ram for rhel 6 to install a graphical interface. just increased the size allocated in virtual box and it worked

Comment: This did the trick for me with Oracle Linux 6.6 (x64) - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should do somethings:

1. Add new user, please don't use root as general user. Set permission for new users.
2. Install X and your favourite GUI, such as GNOME or KDE or something. You can install via yum group install with internet.
3. Set up GDM or KDM (if you don't want, no problem), configure your desktop evironment.

I think RedHat has option for install GUI, so you can mount your CD/DVD then install from it or using internet.

P/S: a book about RedHat should better for you than asking in SO. :D